# Can BigQueryOperator run multiple SQL files?

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I have some SQL to be triggered by airflow BigQueryOperator, one of the SQL is common for all tasks given below situation:

SQL to run - `common.sql`, `abc.sql`, `xyz.sql`

- Task1 - `common.sql + abc.sql`
- Task2 - `common.sql + xyz.sql`

In order for one task run 2 SQL, I read 2 SQL files into a string, then run the merged-string to run task in one go.

Code looks like this:

```
with open ('common.sql', "r") as sqlfile:
     common_array = sqlfile.readlines()

with open ('abc.sql', "r") as sqlfile:
     abc_array    = sqlfile.readlines()
            
# at this point, sql_script has all codes from common.sql and abc.sql
sql_script = ''.join(common_array) + '\n' + ''.join(abc_array)

BigQueryOperator(task_id='task1', sql=sql_script)
```

This serve my purpose, is there any other way that more elegant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reading manually file by file, you can create a list that will contain your files. This will be helpful if you have multiple files. For each file read contents, join it to the `common_array` and create a key value pair per joined common and sql file.

For testing test1.sql, test2.sql, test3.sql and common.sql contains single line query.

```
import json
with open ('common.sql', "r") as sqlfile:
     common_array = sqlfile.readlines()

file_arr = ['test1.sql','test2.sql','test3.sql']
sql_dict = {}
for data in file_arr:
    with open (data, "r") as sqlfile:
        key = data.split('.')[0]
        value = ''.join(common_array) + '\n' + ''.join(sqlfile.read().rstrip())
        sql_dict[key] = value

print(json.dumps(sql_dict, sort_keys=False, indent=2))

print("\nDictionary value for sql_dict['test1']: \n"+ sql_dict['test1'])
```

Output:

```
{
  "test1": "SELECT * FROM `my-project.my_dataset.common` LIMIT 10\n\nSELECT * FROM `my-project.my_dataset.myTable` LIMIT 10",
  "test2": "SELECT * FROM `my-project.my_dataset.common` LIMIT 10\n\nSELECT * FROM `my-project.my_dataset.myTable_2` LIMIT 10",
  "test3": "SELECT * FROM `my-project.my_dataset.common` LIMIT 10\n\nSELECT * FROM `my-project.my_dataset.myTable_3` LIMIT 10"
}

Dictionary value for sql_dict['test1']:
SELECT * FROM `my-project.my_dataset.common` LIMIT 10

SELECT * FROM `my-project.my_dataset.myTable` LIMIT 10
```

You can then use the values in the dictionary to `BigQueryOperator`.

```
BigQueryOperator(task_id='task1', sql=sql_dict['test1'])
```

Comment: Ricco, thanks for answering the question. Your solution is similar, also write the script content to a string then assign to BigQueryOperator parameter. I'm expecting something like assign a filepath, but instead of assign only one file, we can assign multi files. For example: BigQueryOperator(task_id='task1', sql=['common.sql', 'abc.sql'])    (I try this but it won't work). If I can assign filepaths, the codes will look more concise.

Comment: @BrianMo Yes it is quite similar, my solution is intended to remove multiple lines of joining common and sql file. I checked the source code of [BigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.html#BigQueryOperator) and as of now it can only accepts strings thus it is not yet possible to pass a list of sql files. Thus your workaround is your only option for now.